# Find asymptotically equivalent function $f\sim g$

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to find a asymptotically equivalent function $g$ for $f(x)= \sin{(\frac{\pi}{6^x})} - \dfrac{1}{2}$, ie $f \sim g$.

Should I use $\sin{x}$ Taylor expansion or something else?

Here, $x$ approaches to $1$.

Comment: @ Jakobian : sorry, edited, approached to 1

Comment: Yes, I think Taylor series would be the best in here.

Comment: Is it in a neighbour hood of $0$ or of $\infty$ of of $1$?

Comment: @Bernard:  a neighbourhood of 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$(\sin(\pi/6^x)-1/2)' = -\ln 6 \cdot\frac{\pi \cos(\pi/6^x)}{6^x} $$
Taylor formula gives us
$$\sin(\pi/6^x)-1/2 = -\ln 6 \cdot\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{12}(x-1)+o(x-1) $$
so
$$\sin(\pi/6^x)-1/2 \sim -\ln 6 \cdot\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{12}(x-1)$$
as $x\to 1$.

Comment: @Jacobian: Thank you for yor answer. It's interesting that $1/2=\sin(\pi/6)$. Does it make sense?

Comment: You forgot a factor $\pi$ in your derivative.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you kindly

Comment: @Metso What do you mean?

Comment: @Jacobian: I mean in this exercise we can rewrite $\sin(\pi/6^x)-\sin(\pi/6)$. But it does not help. Thank you.